# Symfony - module template not loading withing layout specified in view.yml file

Tags: layout, symfony1

I inherited these symfony source files from a site previously hosted on a linux box, and developed by someone else. 
I'm developing on a Windows XP machine and am trying to make this site work on localhost.

I've made sure that in /apps/frontend/config/view.yml the setting below are there. (And this is a default setting for all site pages.)

> has_layout:     on
>   layout:         layout

And that the selected layout is available and correct in /apps/frontend/templates/layout.php

Yet, whenever I try to load a page, in page source, I can see that it only loads the module template code, without anything around it.

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple issues:

- **An error is thrown in your layout.php** Have you enabled all warnings/errors and checked your log files?
- **It renders the wrong layout somehow** This could happen when you have view setups for different environments. If you add `<?php decorate_with('layout'); ?>` to one of your views (like `indexSuccess.php`, does it work? Is there no override for the project `view.yml` in the module? Or is the template overriden with a `<?php decorate_with(FALSE); ?>` statement?

But my first guess is the top one: enable all logging and view your log.

Comment: I tried adding <?php decorate_with('layout'); ?> to one of the views, no difference. theres no view.yml files overriding the default one, or <?php decorate_with(FALSE); ?> in any of the templates.

Comment: You wouldn't believe this -  there was a mysql connection setup in a template file, that used wrong credentials. And this would make everything crash. 

My fault was that I couldn't predict that a developer would include php mysql connection, database and query functions into a template file lol

Thanks for your help Mr. Grad van Horck

Answer (score 0):

Guess what, it was a syntax error in a config/settings.yml file.

I've put 'true' instead of 'on' and 'false' instead of 'off'. I'm not sure if it was a because the file contained both 'on' and 'true', or if it can only tolerate one or the other depending on version of symfony.

5 days of banging head into keyboard over a stupid file format that has no debug.

I will not use yaml files willingly again.